# VBScript receives syntax error when trying to run SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, vbscript

I have a vbscript that runs a SQL Server script against a database. The script creates a bunch of foreign keys. It works fine if you log into SQL Server Management Studio, choose the correct database from the dropdown menu, copy and paste in the query, and click run.

However, using this VBScript, I receive a syntax error every time:

```
Function runSQL()
  Set objSQLConnection = CreateObject( "ADODB.Connection" )
  Set objSQLData = CreateObject( "ADODB.Recordset" )

  SQLConnectionString = "driver={SQL Server};server=.;Trusted_Connection=yes;database=MyDB"

  objSQLConnection.Open SQLConnectionString

  query = objFSO.openTextFile("MyScript.sql", 1, 0, -2).readAll()

  objSQLData.Open query, objSQLConnection

  objSQLConnection.Close
End Function
```

The exact error is `Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near 'GO'`. It's not particularly helpful because there are a jillion `GO`s in the file.

There's nothing special about the SQL file. It just creates a jillion foreign key constraints. What is going on? I am at wit's end. Potentially relevant is that I had a difficult time reading the file (hence the `openTextFile("MyScript.sql", 1, 0, -2)`).

Comment: Have you tried removing GO in your script?

Comment: I haven't. I was given the script but I'll try removing all `GO`s from it.

Comment: `GO` isn't T-SQL. It's a batch separator, only understood by certain utilities such as SSMS and SQLCMD.

Comment: You do realize that by activating the .readAll() statement off of the openTextFile command, it locks the file for read only and keeps it open? You may want to close out of the file in vbs if you are going to make revisions to it.

Comment: @AaronBertrand, you are great! The answer worked and I really appreciate the explanation. If you submit your comment as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: @Rich I don't believe that's true. He's using an anonymous `TextStream` object here. VBScript creates the `TextStream` object on the fly, calls the `ReadAll()` method on it (which is returned to the `query` variable) and then the "anonymous" `TextStream` object immediately goes out of scope. And when `TextStream` objects go out of scope, they are automatically closed before they are dereferenced and freed. At least that's been my experience.

Comment: @Bond hmmm, i was probably making the assumption directly off the opentextfile() command. Looking at his parameters now i believe you are right. Thanks for stating this. :) siirdank Bond is right.

Comment: @sirdank There's also no need to create a `Recordset` object here. You're not returning any records. Just use `Connection.Execute(...)` to run your SQL statement(s).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GO` si not a T-SQL statement, it's what is called a batch separator. It is understood by tools such as SQL Server Management Studio or command line tool `sqlcmd.exe`.
 It's used to separated statements to be sent to the database engine. In SSMS, for instance, you can use it to show some feedback with `PRINT` in between batches, useful for long running scripts with multiple batches.